"Will man" at the beginning of affirmative sentence
I have seen the following sentence in https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/asien/israel-gallant-abloesung-100.html:

Will man den israelischen Medien Glauben schenken, dann geht es nicht
mehr darum ob, sondern wann Israels Verteidigungsminister Yoav Gallant
abgelöst wird.

The literal translation of the sentence ("Want you to give faith to the Israeli media, then...) doesn't make sense. Is "will man" equivalent to "wenn man" ("if you" in English) ?
Assuming that is true and also that "Glauben schenken" is only a fancy way of saying "glauben", the sentence would make more sense: "If you believe the Israleli media, then..."

You already have a great answer, but if you would like to see more examples you can look for "uneingeleiteter Nebensatz".

"Glauben schenken" underlines that it is somewhat hard to believe, you must be willing to believe it. "Schenken" is a voluntary act, perhaps like in English "granting / conceding something".

In German, you can rephrase conditions by dropping wenn and moving the conjugated verb to the beginning of the clause.

Wenn man einen Bekannten auf der Straße trifft, sollte man den grüßen.
Trifft man einen Bekannten auf der Straße, sollte man den grüßen.

Same in your example:

Wenn man den israelischen Medien Glauben schenken will, …
Will man den israelischen Medien Glauben schenken, …

And yes, Glauben schenken is a fancy way of saying glauben but it's very specific: that Glauben schenken indicates that the information wasn't proofed by a second source.

English also has verb-first-conditionals. But preposing verbs is confined to auxiliaries, and "want" isn't an auxiliary. But consider: "Had I known this  earlier, I wouldn't have..." -- it's clearly possible in the function of an if-clause.
